# What will be output of below php program

Tags: php

I have a program in php that will based on post and pre increment like

```
<?php
$x=5;
echo $x+++$x++;
 ?>
```

I execute program and output is 11 but i confused why it prints 11.can anyone please explain how this program execute.

Comment: I don't know but if I were you I would read about PHP operators precedence first

Comment: i read but according to me the output will be 12

Comment: How do you get that? It could either be 5+6=11 or 6+7=13, I don't see how it could be 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The postincrement operator increments the variable, but returns its old value. So `$x++` is equivalent to:

```
($temp = $x, $x = $x + 1, $temp)
```

When you do it twice in an expression, it's like:

```
echo ($temp1 = $x, $x = $x + 1, $temp1) + ($temp2 = $x, $x = $x + 1, $temp2);
```

The first part sets `$temp1 = 5` and increments `$x` to `6`. The second part sets `$temp2 = 6` and increments `$x` to 7. Then it does `$temp1 + $temp2` and echoes the result, which is `5 + 6 = 11`.

Answer (score 2):

`x++` is called postincrement, it returns `x` and then increases `x` by one. Opposite is `++x` ( preincrement ), increase `x` by one and then return. `+` in the middle is arithmetic operator for addition.

```
$x = 5;

echo $x++ + $x++;    // 11
echo $x;             // 7
```

Answer (score 0):

This: `echo $x+++$x++` is the same as:

```
echo ( ($x++) + ($x++) )
```

So, as you can see, its adding `$x++` plus `$x++`

In PHP, when you run `$x++`, is the same as saying `$x = $x + 1` but returning the original value of `$x`. (As said in the comments)

So for example if you do this:

```
$x = 5;
echo $x++; //outputs $x, then adds 1 
echo $x++; //outputs $x, then adds 1

/*
THIS IS WHAT THE ABOVE DOES:

set x equal to 5
echo x (OUTPUTS 5), then add 1. 
echo x (OUTPUTS 6), then add 1.
*/
```

With that said, in `$x+++$x++`, the first reference of $x is when its value is still 5 (before it is incremented) and the second reference to $x is then when its value is 6 (before it is again incremented), Therefore: `5 + 6 = 11`

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

Comment: `$x++` is the same as saying `$x = $x + 1` (but returns the original value of `$x`).

Comment: but sir if we add two variable the value of $x is same for both variable then why its come 11 .at the same time how we know the value increment or decryment

Comment: @Ankitsingh You're doing `++` twice, each time it adds to the variable.

Comment: when it allocate memory for $x then why its different at same time how we perform any operation,let me clear $x=5 then when we echo this code $x is same 5 for both can you prove it.

Comment: not both i only talk about $x why you treat as two element.

Comment: what do you mean by two elements?

Comment: awesome, hope I helped at least a bit.